# Word for good music that channels a lot of bad energy into good energy

Tags: single-word-requests

There is some word I look to describe good music or some nice activity in general. It is used as in the music (the activity) channels a lot of bad energy into good energy and it begins and makes you feel light at heart, beginning with kata... something... I think.

"This song is really [...] to me."

I heard that word some time ago and now try to remember it, but I just can't.

Comment: Cathartic ? :  related to the  act or process of releasing a strong emotion (such as pity or fear) especially by expressing it in an art form http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catharsis

Comment: @Josh61 *Cathartic*, no?

Comment: Yes! That's it.

Comment: @Josh61: Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: While cathartic may be the word you are looking for, beware of its usage as such. It's a loaded word and cannot be used for  light, soothing / balming activities. Crying over your loss can be cathartic, but going for a walk cannot be, howsoever soothing it may be. See the same link  for more examples : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catharsis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cathartic is the word you are looking for, but soothing/calming comes to mind.

Catharsis is usually only associated with intense emotions.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the word that sums up what you're describing is "therapeutic,"
Which means:

Producing good effects on the body or mind; treatment or cure

Especially in the context you gave: "this song is very therapeutic to me"

Which would mean that the song rejuvenates and heals you, either physically or emotionally.

Merriam-Webster